# How to use child process in nodejs to run multiple functions at once

Tags: node.js, child-process

I would like to make use of node's child process to run three calculations in parallel to make better use of available CPU power but I am not sure on how I could execute them as the examples on the api docs seems to only cover external script files. 
Would it be possible to execute the three functions instead of executing some external scripts ?

Comment: did you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20004935/best-way-to-execute-parallel-processing-in-node-js ?

Comment: I think you are looking for `cluster` in nodejs.

Comment: I am not entirely sure but web workers seem to be what I am after.